# apache cannot import setings with django project

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I want to use django with apache. My directory tree is the following

```
/home/avlahop/development/django/rhombus2
├── accounts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── admin
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── gis
│   └── js
├── customer
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── manage.py
├── media
├── mycal
├── mypil
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── rhombus
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── api.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── rhombus.db
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── scripts
│   ├── create_data_files.py
│   ├── create_data_files.pyc
│   ├── find_server.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   └── populatedb.py
├── settings
├── static
├── tastypie
├── templates
```

wsgi.py

```
import os, sys

root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..')
sys.path.insert(0, root)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "rhombus.settings")



# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)
```

My site.conf file has the following code(and enabled)

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/avlahop/development/django/rhombus2
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmast@rhombus.com
    ServerName myrhombus.com
    ServerAlias www.myrhombus.com
    DocumentRoot /home/avlahop/development/django/rhombus2
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/avlahop/development/django/rhombus2/rhombus/wsgi.py
    <Directory /home/avlahop/development/django/rhombus2/rhombus>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

everything under /home/avlahop/development/django/rhombus2 (including root) is chmoded to 755 that is rx to others. But I get the following error

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'rhombus.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named rhombus.settings
```

What the ... is going wrong here. I have the same thing with another site (another virtualhost in a different conf file) and I get permission denied.And the I copied pasted the above code, and changed paths. So 2 sites same code, different errors. I am really getting frustrated here. I don't want to go to php....Php is so easy to deploy...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#basic-configuration) you should specify python path as following:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com
```

As an alternative, you might want to use [`WSGIDaemonProcess`](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html) directive with `python_path argument` (and this is stated in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode) as well)

```
WSGIDaemonProcess [other args] python-path=/path/to/mysite.com
```

In your case `/path/to/mysite.com` should be `/home/avlahop/development/django/rhombus2`

Also, please note that it's considered a bad practice to put source code under DocumentRoot, as it's (1) not required to run the site and (2) under certain circumstances allows attacker accessing source code. If I'm not mistaking only static files should be located under DocumentRoot.

Comment: but I have it. Look at the first line of my site.conf. What should I put inside DocumentRoot?. Only templates and static?Does that mean that I need to change the templates folder in my settings file? I guess so. This is not very flexible. What if i have many Virtual hosts with different WSGIPythonPath. I cannot put them in one conf. correct?

Comment: Try moving `WSGIPythonPath` up and down the filesystem tree. Templates should be outside DocumentRoot as well. Templates folder should have relative path if I'm not mistaking, so unless you specified absolute path you don't have to change it. If you have many virtual hosts you should configure mod_wsgi for each virtual host.

Comment: Also, the same error appears if it can't import settings file due to some error. Try switching to that virtualenv, run interactive python console and import your settings file - there might be some errors

Comment: I tried...the same error....How many WSGIPythonPath can I set inside a conf file? I am guessing one. So the only way to have one conf for different sites is to have their wsgi.py files inside one directory seperate from django code. I am not inside a virtualenv, normal python. If i run ./manage.py shell i can import rhombus.settings normally. It works in django's test webserver

Comment: Even in plain interactive python shell I can import rhombus.settings.
/home/avlahop/development/django/rhombus2/mycal is in PYTHONPATH (I am not sure why).

Comment: I am this close breaking my office down....I did a system reboot and now it gives me a 403 Forbidden code!!!!!!!!!!And is not working even  if I chmod it to 777....I mean come on!!!!!

Comment: The user that Apache runs as would not normally be able to read into a users home directory. Don't put your site under a users home directory. That or you would have to open up access to the home directory and any directories below it. Read access to just the files is not enough.

Comment: Yes ok...Its not safe...But I have chmoded everything to 777 just to check if it is the permissions that causing the issue..Still I get a 403 forbidden. The Access log shows me that is trying to acces the correct url's. So could you suggest me a good way to in case of directories and permissions so to be able to host different django sites? And an example of different Vhosts inside in one conf file?